# boost::unit_test::data::random(-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) only generates +Infinity

Tags: c++, boost, random

I'm using [`boost::unit_test::data::random`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/unit_test/data/random.html) (with `boost-1.61.0_1` installed) and I'm having some issues generating random floats using `boost::unit_test::data::random(-FLT_MAX,FLT_MAX)`. It only seems to generate `+Infinity`.

Through trial and error, I found that I could generate random floats in `[-FLT_MAX,-FLT_MAX * 2^-25)` and `[-FLT_MAX * 2^-25, FLT_MAX)` separately, which gives me a possible work-around, but I'm still curious as to what I'm doing wrong trying to generate floats in `[-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)`.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE example
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/monomorphic.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <cfloat>

inline void in_range(float const & min, float const & x, float const & max) {
  BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE(min <= x);
  BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE(x < max);
}

static constexpr float lo{-FLT_MAX / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 32.0)};

// this test passes
namespace bdata = boost::unit_test::data;
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(low_floats, bdata::random(-FLT_MAX, lo) ^ bdata::xrange(100), x,
                     index) {
#pragma unused(index)
  in_range(-FLT_MAX, x, lo);
}
// this test passes
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(high_floats, bdata::random(lo, FLT_MAX) ^ bdata::xrange(100), x,
                     index) {
#pragma unused(index)
  in_range(lo, x, FLT_MAX);
}
// this test fails
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(all_floats, bdata::random(-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) ^ bdata::xrange(100), x,
                     index) {
#pragma unused(index)
  in_range(-FLT_MAX, x, FLT_MAX);
}
```

results in:

```
$ ./example
Running 300 test cases...
example.cpp:9: fatal error: in "all_floats": critical check x < max has failed [inf >= 3.40282347e+38]
Failure occurred in a following context:
    x = inf; index = 0; 
...
example.cpp:9: fatal error: in "all_floats": critical check x < max has failed [inf >= 3.40282347e+38]
Failure occurred in a following context:
    x = inf; index = 99; 

*** 100 failures are detected in the test module "example"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::unit_test::data::random` uses [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution), which has the [requirement](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.dist.uni.real#2):

> *Requires:* `a ≤ b` and `b - a ≤ numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`.

In your case, `b - a` is `2 * FLT_MAX`, which is `+Inf` in `float`.

You could use your workaround, or you could generate in `double` and cast back to `float`.